# Display Stock and Out of Stock Products Category Magento

Tags: magento, product

I'm having problem on displaying products that are in stock and out of stock in category page.

Here's the screenshot of my category.

[image]

Those 6 products doesn't have any quantity, in short they're out of stock. But what I want to happen is, even though they're out of stock, I want it to display on the list.

I already did this one

> 1. Login to Magento backend
> 2. Take menu System-Configuration.
> 3. Take inventory tab from the left panel
> 4. Set Display out of stock products to ‘Yes’ in Stock options tab in the right panel

But still, it doesn't work. Here's my code for it.

```
<?php
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
?>
```

And if I count the products

```
$_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count();
echo $_collectionSize;
```

The output is 0, any solution how to display the products even if they're out of stock?
So if I echo it, it should say 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento product display setting is managed from Admin system setting.So,Please go to

```
admin>System Configuration>Catalog>Inventory>Stock Option>
```

and here **Display Out of Stock Products  change to yes** for display all in stock and out stock products in category